# How do posts get closed as duplicates vs exact duplicates?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I've come across some posts that said they were closed as exact duplicates, and some that were closed as duplicates.

[image: duplicate question]

[image: exact duplicate question]

The first image is a duplicate question and the second one is an exact duplicate.

How does a question get closed as a duplicate and how does it get closed as an exact duplicate?

Comment: I believe "exact duplicates" are when the user reposts their question and we catch it and close the repost against the original.